# Mysql join statement performing differently on localhost vs godaddy

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have the following statement :

```
 SELECT * FROM (`titles`) 
 INNER JOIN `mastercat` 
 ON `mastercat`.`PeriodID` = `titles`.`PeriodID` 
 ORDER BY `titles`.`PeriodID`
```

My godaddy account has the exact information which my localhost account has.  But when I run it on godaddy I get double the results...

When I run it on the localhost i get the intended (and correct) results.

I was using codeigniators activerecord previous to just typing in a sql query and in both cases the same issue came up.

Has anyone seen this?  What was the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very strong likelihood that the dataset between your localhost database and go-daddy database is different.
I would also suggest several things.

1. Fully qualify the database name in you select query, to ensure that the correct schema is selected

2. Perform a select count(*) from each of your tables in doubt and compare results between your localhost and go-daddy host, to ensure that they each have the same number of records.

Comment: This is what happens when I release a page and panic when something isn't 100% :).  I had the joining table have duplicate results...  It was an error when I imported it.  Thanks.